# SELECT * FROM `uts` WHERE MONTH_YEAR BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('Apr-16','%m-%y) and STR_TO_DATE('Mar-17','%m-%y)

Tags: mysql, sql

select * from `uts` where month_year is not null and (str_to_date(concat('o1-',month_year),'%d-%m-%y') between str_to_date('01-apr-16','%d-%m-%y') and str_to_date('31-mar-17','%d-%m-%y'))

as my data is stored in string Apr-16 May-16 i want to get the data from apr to mar financial year

Comment: Why on earth are you storing dates as strings?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because parsing and casting is funner than a barrel of monkeys

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `uts` 
WHERE MONTH_YEAR IS NOT NULL AND (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('O1-',MONTH_YEAR),'%d-%m-%y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-Apr-16','%d-%m-%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31-Mar-17','%d-%m-%y'));
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0100 seconds.)
SELECT * FROM `uts` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('O1-',MONTH_YEAR),'%d-%m-%y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-Apr-16','%d-%m-%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31-Mar-17','%d-%m-%y')

Comment: Is `MONTH_YEAR` nullable?

Comment: MONTH_YEAR  varchar(30)  latin1_swedish_ci   No  None

Comment: That means its nullable, that could be the issue. I will correct the query.

Comment: NO ROWS SELECTED

Comment: What's the format of MONTH_YEAR? Is it something like 'Jan-18' or '01-18'?